# TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null when using yarn pnp and typescript4

Tags: typescript, jestjs, antlr4, yarnpkg-v3

I am trying [antlr4ts-sql](https://github.com/modeldba/antlr4ts-sql) in my project, which is part of monorepo using jazelle, typescript, yarn pnp.

Versions are:

```
% jz version
actual: 0.0.0-standalone.82
system: 0.0.0-standalone.74

% yarn -v
3.3.0
```

My codes (from antlr4ts-sql repo):

```
import { antlr4tsSQL, SQLDialect } from 'antlr4ts-sql';

export class Experiment {
  public exp() {
    const antlr4tssql = new antlr4tsSQL(SQLDialect.MYSQL);
    const query = 'SELECT * FROM table1';
    const parseTree = antlr4tssql.getParseTreeFromSQL(query);
    console.log(parseTree);
  }
}
```

but I got the following errors:

```
    TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

    > 1 | import { antlr4tsSQL, SQLDialect } from 'antlr4ts-sql';
        | ^
      2 |
      3 |
      4 | export class Experiment {

      at Object.<anonymous> (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/antlr4ts-npm-0.5.0-dev-7e0fc8988a-640dae2229.zip/node_modules/src/tree/xpath/XPathLexer.ts:18:33)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/antlr4ts-npm-0.5.0-dev-7e0fc8988a-640dae2229.zip/node_modules/src/tree/xpath/XPath.ts:16:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/antlr4ts-npm-0.5.0-dev-7e0fc8988a-640dae2229.zip/node_modules/src/tree/xpath/index.ts:6:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/antlr4ts-npm-0.5.0-dev-7e0fc8988a-640dae2229.zip/node_modules/src/tree/index.ts:18:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/antlr4ts-npm-0.5.0-dev-7e0fc8988a-640dae2229.zip/node_modules/src/index.ts:9:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/antlr4ts-sql-npm-1.1.0-d18d4988c9-79289d09ea.zip/node_modules/antlr4ts-sql/index.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/autocomplete/experiments.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/autocomplete/index.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/index.ts:1:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/autocomplete/antlr4ts-sql.test.ts:1:1)
at module.exports (../../../../../common/@company/jest-config-utils/test-runner.js:19:44)
```

when I unzip `antlr4ts-sql-npm-1.1.0-d18d4988c9-79289d09ea.zip` from `.yarn/cache`, I got the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dNmB.png)

it seems that there are `XPathLexer.js` and `XPathLexer.d.ts` in the unzip `node_modules/dist/tree/xpath` (which are Generated from XPathLexer.g4 by ANTLR 4.7.3-SNAPSHOT). but from the error message, test-runner.js is looking for `at Object.<anonymous> (../../../../../../.yarn/cache/antlr4ts-npm-0.5.0-dev-7e0fc8988a-640dae2229.zip/node_modules/src/tree/xpath/XPathLexer.ts:18:33)` but `XPathLexer.ts` does not exist in the [source code](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4ts/tree/master/src/tree/xpath) and does not exist in the `antlr4ts-sql-npm-1.1.0-d18d4988c9-79289d09ea.zip` of `.yarn/cache`

I am new to yarn pnp, not sure whether this is expected. My understanding is that `jest` should read antlr4ts-sql and antlr4ts from the zip file, but the errors means that they are not reading the zip files.

I guess something wrong with my deps and config.

tsconfig.json is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "lib": [
      "es6"
    ],
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.*",
    "__tests__/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

package.json is

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "antlr4ts-sql": "^1.1.0",
    "assert": "1.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "jest-pnp-resolver": "1.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "28.1.3",
    "jest": "28.1.3",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "28.1.3",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-global": "3.1.2",
    "patch-package": "6.2.2",
    "prettier": "^2.8.0",
  },
...
```

I am stuck in this question for several days. Any comments welcomed. thanks